# Time Filter field name: @timestamp in Kibana

Tags: logstash, kibana, logstash-grok

The date and time format in my log file is as follow:

```
[29/02/2020 07:34:27.805] - sc879537 - 10.107.172.25 - 12 - Transaction 2659 COMPLETED 6849 ms wait time 3597 ms
```

I would like this value to be populated into the field: @timestamp in Kibana, as at the moment it contains the index action time, and not the log record time.
Here's my logstash conf file :

```
input {
    file { 
        path => "/home/mathis/Documents/intranet-2020-02-25-8400.log"
        start_position => "beginning"
    }
}
filter {
    grok {
        match => { "message" => ["\[%{DATESTAMP:logdate}\] \- %{USERNAME:user} \- %{IPV4:clientip} \- %{NUMBER} \- %{WORD} %{NUMBER:exectime} %{WORD} %{NUMBER:time} %{GREEDYDATA:data} %{NUMBER:waittime}"] }
        remove_field => "message"
    }
    date {
            match => [ "logdate", "MM/dd/YYYY HH:mm:ss.SSS" ]
    }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "127.0.0.1:9200"
        index => "logstash-local3-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem, here's my conf file :

```
input {
    file { 
        path => "/home/mathis/Documents/intranet-2020-02-25-8400.log"
        start_position => "beginning"
        sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
    }
}
filter {
    grok {
        match => { "message" => ["\[%{DATESTAMP:eventtime}\] \- %{USERNAME:user} \- %{IPV4:clientip} \- %{NUMBER} \- %{WORD} %{NUMBER:exectime} %{WORD} %{NUMBER:time} %{GREEDYDATA:data} %{NUMBER:waittime}"] }
        remove_field => "message"
    }
    date {
            match => [ "eventtime", "dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss.SSS" ]
        target => "@timestamp"
    }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "127.0.0.1:9200"
        index => "logstash-local3-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    }
}
```